# Find out how many ring homomorphism exist

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Consider $R=\mathbb{Z}_{11}\ \ $   $S=\mathbb{Z[\sqrt5]}=\{a+b\sqrt5: a,b \in \mathbb{Z} \}$

find out how many there is homomorpshism from $f:R\to S$ and $g:S \to R$

I think first ring isomorphsms solves this problem but I have some problems. First I think we need to find all of ideals in $R,S$ because $R$ is a field then it has only $2$ ideals $\{ 0\}, \mathbb{Z_{11}}$ but $S$ is not a field and I have some problems with finding ideals, then considering $R \to S$ homomorpsihms we have that $im(f)$ is isomorphic with $\{0\}, \mathbb{Z_{11}}$ how to find then $f$ where $im(f)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_{11}}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we look at an arbitrary homomorphism (of rings or groups, it doesn't matter) $f:R\to S$. It is uniquely determined by $f(1)$. However, note that we need
$$
0 = f(0) = f(11\cdot 1) = 11\cdot f(1)
$$
This means that $f(1) = 0$, since $11$ is not a zero divisor in $S$. So there is only one homomorphism $R\to S$, and that is the trivial one.

For the other way, say we have a homomorphism $g:S\to R$. It is characterised by $g(1)$ and $g(\sqrt 5)$. If $g$ is only an additive group homomorphism, then these may be chosen freely, and we have that there are $121$ different homomorphisms.

On the other hand, if we want these to be *ring* homomorphisms, then we would need two things to hold: $g(1)^2 = g(1)$, and $g(\sqrt5)^2 = 5g(1)$. The first one limits the possible $g(1)$ to $0$ or $1$. If we choose $g(1) = 0$, then we must also have $g(\sqrt5) = 0$ because of the second constraint. If we choose $g(1) = 1$, then we need $g(\sqrt5)^2 = 5$. This has the two solutions $\pm 4$ or in other words $4$ and $7$. So to recap, these are the three possible ring homomorphisms

- $g_1(1) = 0, g_1(\sqrt5) = 0$
- $g_2(1) = 1, g_2(\sqrt5) = 4$
- $g_3(1) = 1, g_3(\sqrt5) = 7$

Final note: If you also require that a general ring homomorphisms $h:A\to B$ fulfill $h(1) = 1$, then the $f$ and $g_1$ found above are not considered ring homomorphisms, so instead of one homomorphism $R\to S$ and three homomorphisms $S\to R$, you get no homomorphisms and two homomorphisms respectively.

Comment: thanks  a lot for detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:R \rightarrow S$ be a ring homomorphism. Since $R$ is cyclic, $f$ is determined by $f(1) \in S$. However, since $f$ is homomorphism, we must have $0 = f(0) = f(11) = 11 f(1)$, but $f(1) = a + b \sqrt(5)$ cannot satisfy $11f(1)=0$ unless $f(1)=0$, so there are no such morphisms $f$.